# How to do a query with mulitple joins in AR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My simplified database :

[image]

For example, I would like to get all pois with way_id = 2 (through track_ways & poi_tracks)

I have a scope in my way model :

`scope :by_way, ->(way_id) { joins(:ways).where('ways.id = ?', way_id) }`

I'm using this scope in my query :

`Poi.joins(:tracks).where(tracks: Track.by_way(2))`

But the result is not the expected one

Comment: Try with `Poi.joins(poi_tracks: { track: :track_ways }).where(track_ways: { way_id: 2 })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoiler:

```
Poi.joins(poi_tracks: [track: [:track_ways, :ways]]).where('ways.id = ?', 2)
```

First join with poi_tracks

```
Poi.joins(:poi_tracks).all
```

Join with tracks

```
Poi.joins(poi_tracks: [:track]).all
```

Join with track_ways

```
Poi.joins(poi_tracks: [track: [:track_ways]]).all
```

Join with ways

```
Poi.joins(poi_tracks: [track: [:track_ways, :ways]])
```

Apply way condition

```
 Poi.joins(poi_tracks: [track: [:track_ways, :ways]]).where('ways.id = ?', 2)
```